# Auto removal of buttons in Macro excel sheet on hiding a row and saving the file

Tags: vba, excel

I am preparing an organisation chart wherein a small command button is incorporated in the cell which can expand further levels under him/her. On hiding all the low level files and saving the macro excel sheet, only the top level button is visible. Rest all buttons are removed.

I can see that the program for the buttons are still available in VBA code , but the buttons are not available. I tried to redo the activity multiple times, but the result is same.

Can anyone help me understand the reason of the problem. How can i trace the missing command button in macro sheet?[Layout of my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z757s.png)[My VBA code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZRWi.png)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the button you have to show better want you  precisely mean?

Comment: Ans can you post the code you are working with, please?

Comment: @BennoGrimm: I have added images of screen layout and VBA code in description of the problem. You can see that there is a button in the first column. Similarly I placed commandbuttons in cells B7 and B22. They are getting removed after saving.

Comment: Are you using different types of  CommandButtons (Formula and ActiveX)?

Comment: @BennoGrimm: No, all the buttons are of Form Control only.

Comment: have you tried checking the Top and Left properties of the Button to see if there are still there?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use **.Visible** than to remove the control altogether, else you will have to recreate every time.

[control].Visible = False

Comment: Hi @DayLove.01: I tried with the code 'CommandButton21.Visible = True' but it didnt show up.

Comment: @GouthamRam have you tried clicking 'Design Mode'.  I had a similar experience where a hidden list box disappeared, I thought it was deleted so i went to design mode to recreate it and there it was right where I left it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a std bug in VBA where, on hiding the rows, the length and breadth of the buttons become zero.

Ref: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/779868-buttons-disappear-when-rows-are-hidden-unhidden-in-2010-a.html
(I am not sure, if I can post link of other forums)

As a remedy, I included code to make sure all the rows are 'unhidden' before closing/saving the file. Thus none of the buttons will be removed.

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Range("1:1000").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub

We can close the thread now.